# drawing multiple rect on canvas in p5.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, processing, p5.js

What I want to achieve is multiple rectangles going from bottom to top in p5.js

Here is my code.

```
var j = 0;
var allRectangles = [];
//initaial value of the rectanlge!
var rects = {
    x:window.innerWidth/2,
    y:innerHeight-200    
};
allRectangles.push(rects);
function setup(){
    createCanvas(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);
    generateRectangles();
}
function draw(){
    clear();
    j++;
    allRectangles[j].y--;
    //check();
    rect(allRectangles[j].x,allRectangles[j].y-j,200,40);
}
/*function check(){
    if(allRectangles[j].y < 0){
        allRectangles[j].y = innerHeight-200;;
    }
}*/
//
function generateRectangles(){
    for(var i = 0 ; i<= 50000 ; i++){
        rects = {
            x:random(0,width),
            y:innerHeight-200-(i+1*2)    
        };
        allRectangles.push(rects);
    }
}
```

This code is very simple,I have a rect in which I reduce the y position each time the draw() function runs,for this to work properly I need to have a clear function so that it removes the rectangle which it drew and draw that rectangle with -1 value of y.

In setup function I have all the rectangles in a array which has the random x value and same Y value.

But for some reason the same rectangle is draw over and over again with the x,y position of the new rectangles. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

> I have all the rectangles in a array which has the random x value and same Y value

This is not true. Your generateRectangles() function gives rects.y a value based on the increasing value of i.

> same rectangle is draw[sic] over and over again with the x,y position of the new rectangles. Am I missing something here?

Your function call tells it to draw a 200x40 rectangle at the location:

```
rect(allRectangles[j].x,allRectangles[j].y-j,200,40)
```

What size were you expecting?

Comment: I am not able to understand what you are trying to say to me.

Comment: You stated that it draws the same size rectangle at the new x.y positions as if it's not supposed to do that. What should it do?

Comment: You also stated that your code creates rectangles with a random X and the same Y, but that's not what your code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Please think about exactly what your `draw()` function is doing.

```
function draw(){
    clear();
    j++;
    allRectangles[j].y--;
    //check();
    rect(allRectangles[j].x,allRectangles[j].y-j,200,40);
}
```

- First your clear out any old frames.
- Then you increase `j` by `1`.
- Then you decrease the `y` position of the `jth` rectangle by `1`.
- Then you draw the `jth` rectangle.
- Then `draw()` fires again, and you clear out the rectangle you just drew and you move on to the next one.

Once you draw a rectangle, you never return to it. You have 50000 rectangles, and for each one you move it up by 1 pixel and then draw it, then clear it out and draw the next one.

Get rid of the call to `clear()` to better see what's going on.

Comment: I know it is because of the clear(). The code which is given here is just part of my application, there is a ellipses which need the clear function and that is why I have it. The ellipses moves with the cursor and there is rectangle which comes from bottom

Comment: Is there any other thing by which I can clear the ellipses but not the rectangles?

Comment: @this.Believer Sure, you could draw the rectangles to a buffer using the `createGraphics()` function. See [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createGraphics) or do a search on this site for more info.